# How to update multibinding manually

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, multibinding

I had a problem with the `Binding`. The `Rectangle.Fill` dependency property was bound to an `ObservableCollection` with the converter. Although the `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the binding was not updated. I managed, however, to solve this by attaching my delegation to the collection's change notification event and refreshing the binding manually:

```
    void ColorsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression b = colorRectangle.GetBindingExpression(Rectangle.FillProperty);
        if (b != null)
            b.UpdateTarget();
    }
```

Lately, however, I changed the `Binding` to `MultiBinding`, and the above solution stopped working (the `b` is `null`). Is there a way to force the `Multibinding` to update the target property?

Best regards -- Spook.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why the Binding/Multibinding is not responding to the CollectionChanged events?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For a multibinding, the binding expression is a `MultiBindingExpression`, which inherits from `BindingExpressionBase`, but not from `BindingExpression`. So `GetBindingExpression` returns null for a multibinding. Instead you can use `BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression`:

```
MultiBindingExpression b = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(colorRectangle, Rectangle.FillProperty);
```

Comment: mostly getBinding is used for Manual Source Update...
and for that you can use the generalized: `BindingExpressionBase be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(colorRectangle, Rectangle.FillProperty);`  this way it doesn't matter if it is Binding, MultiBinding or any other that will come later.